# Открыть доступ к localhost

Tags: localhost

Вот интересуюсь каким образом открыть localhost для другого юзера, тобишь чтоб он ввел мой IP и видел мой сайт на локалке. Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом это реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно выключить файрволл, либо открыть порт 80 на ПК, а так же роутере, модеме или что там у вас ещё есть. 
В настройках хостов должны быть `*:80`

---

Ни каких дополнительных действий над хостом не требуется

Answer (score 2):

Есть отличный вариант: [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com/).

Качаешь небольшой клиент, выполняешь в командной строке что-то типа: `P:\ath\to\ngrok.exe http 80` и всё.
Выдаются внешние адреса вида:

```
http://a76b8f94.ngrok.io -> localhost:80
https://a76b8f94.ngrok.io -> localhost:80
```

Конечно, у Вас должен быть сервер (или что-то, что может принять запрос и дать ответ) на локалке и нужном порту.

Answer (score 1):

Прописываем **VirtualHOST** на той машине где поднят веб-сервер

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/webserver/webname/www"
    ServerName webname
    ErrorLog "C:/webserver/webname/error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/webserver/webname/access.log" common
    <Directory "C:/webserver/webname/www">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Если надо, чтобы обращение с другого компьютера происходило именно по имени компьютера на котором находиться сайт (или что там еще...), необходимо настраивать DNS Server. А так если все компы в локалке, то просто вписываем IP адрес веб-сервера в браузере и должны увидеть сайт.

Ну а так вообще [здесь](https://www.google.ru/#hl=ru&newwindow=1&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF+%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%83+%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8&oq=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF+%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%83+%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i5i30l3.4926.5375.1.5602.3.3.0.0.0.0.54.147.3.3.0...0.0...1c.1.BtlckTQa9xc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.bGE&fp=a3d8d692ed37c82d&biw=1280&bih=773) инфы поболее...

Comment: при чём тут VirtualHost?

Comment: при чём...?

Comment: можно создать на сервере один сайт и вообще не использовать ни где VirtualHost, и при этом он будет прекрасно доступен из интернета

Comment: помнится, мне это еще мой дед говорил